# Problem with manipulation of colored graph

Tags: graphs

Consider a finite set of colors and a given an unweighted graph with the following properties:

1) Graph is connected.

2) All vertices of the graph has a color in the given set of colors.

3) No two adjacent vertices have the same color.

Define a `flip` as the following: change the color of a given vertex `V` AND all reachable vertices from `V` only if those reachable vertices have the same original color with `V` (that is, all vertices that have a path to V consisting of only vertices of the same colors have their color changed).

What's the optimal strategy to find the smallest amount of `flip` in order so that all vertices have the same color?

For example the following graph needs 2 `flips`:

`R
| \
B  B
|  |
Y  Y`

First `flip` is from vertex red to color blue:

`B
| \
B  B
|  |
Y  Y`

Then flip the top blue vertex and change it to yellow, triggering all the other blue vertices to yellow:

`Y
| \
Y  Y
|  |
Y  Y`

I was thinking of exploring all possibilities by try flipping all vertices, but this seems to be inefficient as I might have to explore all the flipping possibilities before finding the optimal one.